# Mutiple Routes in DNN Service Route Mapper not working

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dotnetnuke

i am starting with DNN and was trying to setup a controller and service routes but for some reason it is not working i guess i may be missing something or have the wrong understanding as in how it works

i have a controller as with two actions

```
public class Name : DnnApiController{

  public GetApple(string id){

  }

 public GetOrange(string id){

  }
}
```

I have created service Routes as

```
public class RouteMapper : IServiceRouteMapper
{
    public void RegisterRoutes(IMapRoute mapRouteManager)
    {
        mapRouteManager.MapHttpRoute("Name", "Apple1", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new[] {"MyServices"});

      mapRouteManager.MapHttpRoute("Name", "Orange2", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new[] {"MyServices"});
    }
}
```

When i run it only one of the action is resolved and i get a 400 for the other one...

Any suggestions? why?

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring your routes in the follwoing way

```
routeManager.MapHttpRoute("ModuleName", "Apple1", "{controller}/{action}/{ID}", new string[] { "YourNameSpace.Services.Controllers" });
```

Make sure you get the YourNameSpace replaced as your name space for the module and Your Module Name

What url are you requesting to get the service?

THis assumes the following type of set up:

```
namespace Services.Controllers
{
    public class NameServiceController: DnnApiController, IServiceRouteMapper
    {
    }
}
```

Also, I am pretty sure your controller class name needs to end with the Controller word and when you reference the url you leave out the controller

so the url format is as follows:

DesktopModules / [ModuleName] / api / [ControllerName (with controller removed form the end)] / [Action Name] / [id]

www.yourportal.com/desktopmodules/ModuleName/NameService/Apple1/ID

Hope this helps

Comment: does the ModuleName you specify in the route actually have to exist as a module in DNN? Or does DNN ignore it if the folder doesn't exist and just use it as the route you specified in your route map?

Comment: I'm not an expert but I am pretty sure you need the folder/module name (they match).  Also, I can't think of a use case where you would not use the module name?